# React: deletion of component from an array of components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am initialising `myComponents` array with `useState` hook

```js
const [myComponents, setMyComponents] = useState([])
```

Then I am adding components to the array upon clicking of a button

```js
setMyComponents([...myComponents, <MyComponent />])
```

*MyComponent:*

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div class="flex">
      <button>DELETE</button>
      <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When any of the DELETE buttons pressed, relevant *MyComponent* from the `myComponents` array should be removed. I cannot figure out how to get a reference to the component I have to delete. I cannot use the array index since when the first component is removed from the array, previous indices are no longer valid.

Please let me know how can I delete a particular MyComponent from the array so that it won't affect subsequent deletions.

Comment: It's not a good idea to store components or any complex objects in state https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976609/how-to-store-react-component-in-state-and-pass-a-callback-function

Comment: @diedu Thanks and I think that SO question will guide me to get what I want... Thanks again

Comment: Why don't you use Map instead of array?

Comment: @PiyushN Yes, I will have to keep the data that will be needed by the component in an array and will use .map to create the Component array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is not how you would go about rendering data in react  , generally you would map over a list of data and render components like this below , so when you need to remove an item you just remove the item from the data list and the Listcomponent will re-render with the new data  :

```
function MyComponent(props) {
const {index,text,deleteItem} = props
  return (
    <div class="flex">
      <button onClick={e=>deleteItem(index)}>DELETE</button>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

function MyComponentList(props) {
  const [mydata, setmydata] = useState(["text1","text2","text3"])

 const deleteItem=(index)=>{
      const filterdData= [...mydata].filter((data,i)=> i != index)
      setmydata(filterdData)
 }
  return (
     {
        mydata.map((text,index)=><MyComponent key={index} text={text} index={index} deleteItem= {deleteItem} />
     }
  )
}
```

Comment: I am new to React and I learned a lot from your answer, in addition to getting my question answered. Thanks again (Y)